# Missing context menu item "Suppress Message" from the Visual Studio 2008 Error List Pane

Tags: visual-studio-2008

What do you do to fix the missing context menu item "Suppress Message" from Visual Studio's (2008) "Error List" pane?  This context menu item used to appear when right clicking on a code analysis error and was the last item in the menu.

I have already tried resetting all settings, and tried other projects/solutions. Also, I have Visual Studio 2010 installed, and this context menu item is present and working in 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of my problem turned out to be an update for Visual Studio Team System 2008 Development Edition "KB974558".  After uninstalling it, the context menu item came back.  To uninstall go to the "Uninstall or change a program" menu in Windows 7 and click on "View installed updates" on the left task pane to see all updates.

This same update was causing the VS performance profiler not to function at all.  These two symptoms were seen on several other coworkers machines with the same update installed.

I wasn't able to find this problem anywhere on the internet so that's why I created the question. But if there are any other circumstances that could cause the same problem, please post more answers.

Comment: +1 Well spotted! I can confirm this bug (missing "Suppress Message" menu option). Weird. Note: KB974558 is the "Visual Studio Team System 2008 Service Pack 1 Forward Compatibility Update for Team Foundation Server 2010" that allows VS2008 to connect to VS2010 TFS.